# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource - New One

Tags: java, oracle12c

I have Standalone application which has been migrated from Oracle 11g to 12c.I have changed the jar file from 
`ojdbc14.jar` to `ojdbc7.jar` (JVM version is 7).In Code also i have changed the `oracle.jdbc.driverType.OracleTypes` to `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes` also oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource 
is mapping to Ojdbc7.jar.its working in local but its failing DEV Env with above exception.
PS:-All the neccesary dependency also kept in lib folder and ojdbc14.jar has been replaced with ojdbc7.jar in DEV ENV,but still its throwing the above exception.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: @Jean its resolved..bcs unix soft link refer to different location of lib.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a classpath issue. This class oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource is in ojdbc7.jar. You can check your classpath by looking at how java is launched in the DEV environment (the classpath is often set in the command line).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from checking it is in the classpath, make sure that the file permissions for directory and jar file is properly set so that your application can access it.